# How to make separate home pages for wordpress subdomains (subdomains with single site)

Tags: wordpress, multisite

We have a single site, in this we want multiple subdomain with the same website, for that we are using wildcard subdomains, So our requirement is to create country/subdomain specific homepages for each subdomains.
Example: india.example.com it redirects to homepage1
         africa.example.com it redirects to homepage2

Is there any possibilities for this?

Comment: I guess, you should try [WordPress multi-site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup multisites using [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) feature.
2. Suppose if you setup two multisites e.g. `africa.example.com` and `india.example.com`. Go to `africa.example.com/wp-admin` >> `Appearance` and select the preferred theme. Go to `india.example.com/wp-admin` >> `Appearance` and select the preferred theme.
3. Both the subsites will point to different homepages. If you want to customize the homepages then you need to create [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and add changes accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You should setup the Multi-Site and follow the below URl will help for the how to setup multi-site.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Comment: Above method is done, my question is, after completing above all method, i need to set separate home pages for each subdomains? How?

Comment: You need to customize theme's home page then. Refer [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-homepage-in-wordpress/)

Comment: what i'm trying to convey is, if i open india.example.com i need to get homepage1.    If i open africa.example.com i should get homepage2. (different homepages for different subdomains)